# How to reference the namespace from the design bundle in Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I just read the following note in the documentation:

> Use the `<sfdc:object>` tag set to specify which objects your component is valid for. If an object is installed from a package, add the namespace__ string to the beginning of the object name when including it in the `<sfdc:object>` tag set. For example: objectNamespace__ObjectApiName__c.

How can I dynamically reference the namespace if I have stored it in some configuration class, settings or whatever?

Comment: Is this for your own managed package, or one you've installed? What's the purpose behind doing this?

Comment: I found out how to fix it. You don't need to do anything. Salesforce is automatically managing it. Magic!

Comment: Yeah, I kind of suspected that may be the case. Salesforce does quite a bit of magic for us developers.